# WCF remoting client connection error: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

When I run the client code, the connection instantly breaks on the first attempt to call a method on the IWcfServer interface, with this message:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'The socket connection was aborted. 
This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. 
Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.6090000'.'
```

This all happens within a a second of calling the client code.

Server code:

```
    Dim binding As New NetTcpBinding()

    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)

    Dim baseAddress As New Uri($"net.tcp://192.168.1.1:8025/WcfServer")

    _serviceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(WcfServer), baseAddress)
    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IWcfServer), binding, baseAddress)

    _serviceHost.Open()
```

Client code:

```
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    var url = $"net.tcp://192.168.1.1:8025/WcfServer";
    var address = new EndpointAddress(url);
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWcfServer>(binding, address);

    ClientData = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

And calling a method on the interface is very simple:

```
var ret = _ClientData.GetMethod(parameter);
```

Comment: Bro, have you solved the problem? if possible, please share the solution with me. Frankly speaking, the exception ever happened to me. Somehow it is solved by some settings. But I don't know exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: Not at all, I ended up forming a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092580/wcf-securitytokenvalidationexception-using-self-created-certificate

Answer (score 0):

By default, Nettcpbinding use the Transport security mode, and the client credential type is windows.
Thereby, we should provide the Windows credential on the client-side when calling the service.
In addition, TCP communication is also protected by the windows firewall, please close the firewall and try it again.
Finally, Adding Console.Readline() to prevent the service host from closing automatically.

```
using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
            {
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("serivce is ready....");
                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }
```

**Updated:**

Server side(Console application)

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
        {
            sh.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("serivce is ready....");
            Console.ReadLine();
            sh.Close();
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();

}
public class MyService : IService
{

    public string Test()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

App.config(Server)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="VM1.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" >
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5566"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client.

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://10.157.13.69:5566");
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";
        IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();
}
```

Result.
[image]
[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks, but none of this helps at all.  I already haven't closed the service, firewall was off and have specified no security on both sides with Security.Mode and Transport.ProtectionLevel both set to "None".

Comment: Are you able to access the service decription page on the other computer?

Comment: We had better use MEX endpoint to publish the service metadata. then we could test whether the service is available by adding service reference in the another project.

Comment: I make a simple demo, wish it is useful to you.