# WCF SecurityTokenValidationException using self-created certificate

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, certificate

I'm experiencing a problem with WCF client connections using a self-created certificate.

Certificate created as follows:

```
Makecert -r -pe -n "CN=MySslSocketCertificate" -b 01/01/2015 -e 01/01/2025 -sk exchange -ss my
```

Server code:

```
Public Sub StartWcfServer()
    Dim binding As New NetTcpBinding()

    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport
    binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
    Dim baseAddress As New Uri($"net.tcp://192.168.1.1:1234/WcfServer")

    _serviceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(WcfServer), baseAddress)
    _serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "MySslSocketCertificate")
    _serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    _serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None
    _serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IWcfServer), binding, baseAddress)
    _serviceHost.Open()
End Sub

Private Function ValidateServerCertificate(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

Client code:

```
private void InitialiseWcfClient()
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

    var url = $"net.tcp://192.168.1.1:1234/WcfServer";
    var address = new EndpointAddress(url);
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWcfServer>(binding, address);

    WcfServer = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
}

// call to server which causes the error
WcfServer.CallMethod();
```

Client-side error:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: 'The X.509 certificate CN=MySslSocketCertificate chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

Server-side error:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'
```

Comment: .... there should be a setting somewhere

Comment: @Stefan that's a very generic comment :-)

Comment: Yes, I don't know it from the top of my head.... and didn't use it with WCF, but practically all other libraries allows you to define the level of security on TSL, or rule out some exceptions..... that's all I know, but I think there will be something similar in WCF.   :-/

Comment: You might solve your problem by making a more proper-looking client certificate (add `-eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2` to your makecert command).  That might not be enough, though.

Answer (score 0):

Bro,regardless of whether we specify the Authencation mode on the server-side, we should establish the trust relationship between the server and the client when authenticating the client with a certificate.
Namely, we should install the server certificate on the client-side and install the client certificate on the server side. Based on the authentication mode value, the certificate installation place is difference, commonly we should install it in the Local CA. Besides, considering some access permission issues, we had better install the certificate in Local machine store location other than Current User.
Also, when we explicitly specify the security mode to Transport, we should provide a certificate on the server side.

```
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
```

At the same time, the client is supposed to provide a certificate to represent identity.

```
factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9ee8be61d875bd6e1108c98b590386d0a489a9ca");
```

I have made a demo, ,wish it is helpful to you.
**Server.**

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
        {
            sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
            sh.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("serivce is ready....");
            Console.ReadLine();
            sh.Close();
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();

}
public class MyService : IService
{

    public string Test()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

**App.config(Server side)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="VM1.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" bindingConfiguration="mybinding">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5566"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="mybinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client.**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://vabqia969vm:5566");
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
        factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9ee8be61d875bd6e1108c98b590386d0a489a9ca");
        IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }

}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();

}
```

Result.
[image]
One more thing must be noted that we should ensure the client certificate have the client authentication Intended purposes.
[image]

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.